# Magento 2 Custom module default.xml CSS not called

Tags: theme, css, magento-2.2.5

I've my module files as following

> app/code/Vendor/GeoIp/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Vendor_GeoIp::css/popup.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

My CSS file at following path

> app/code/Vendor/GeoIp/view/frontend/web/css/popup.css

Other code of module is working fine, I cleared cache,s:upgrade,s:s:d many times but it isn't working.

I can't find any mistake in above code. What is wrong?

Comment: please check file permission for that css file

Comment: @JimitBhavsar For testing purpose I've given 777 to module.

Comment: @JimitBhavsar Please check in the browser console. It displays 404 or not?

Comment: @JimitBhavsar No its not there too

Comment: did you copy pasted the Packagename_modulename from registration.php in above css source?

Comment: @oscprofessionals No it is manually written.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your css in  `magento_theme/css` directory and then run deploy command.